# How to get FormControl to recheck validation for FormGroup with Reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation

I am getting to know Form validation with Angular 9 Reactive forms.

I have a form group for a reactive form.  My form only has 2 input elements in it, the form controls areaNameFormComponent and areaDescriptionFormComponent make up this form.  Before they submit I also want to make sure they have chosen at least one state from a component that is nested inside the form.  My third FormControl "statesChosenFormComponent" is in regards to this, but I can't get the FormGroup to check it's validation again to see if the "statesChosen" array has any states added to it.

```
    this.naturalAreaFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  areaNameFormComponent: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  areaDescriptionFormComponent: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  statesChosenFormComponent: new FormControl('stateschosen', [this.checkForStatesChosen()])
});



checkForStatesChosen(): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
  const forbidden = this.statesChosen.length === 0;
  if (!forbidden) {
    alert('not forbidden')
    return null;
  } else {
    alert('forbidden');
    return {nostatechosen: {value: control.value}};
  }
  // return forbidden ? {nostatechosen: {value: control.value}} : null;

};
```

}

```html
<p>natural-area-add works!</p>
<br />
<div *ngIf='stateChosen'>
State Chosen: {{stateChosen.name}}
</div>
<br />
Add state to area:
<app-states (stateChangedEvent)="stateChanged($event)" ></app-states>
<button (click)="addStateToArea()">Add state</button>


<br />
<form [formGroup]="naturalAreaFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="addNaturalArea()">
  statesChosen: {{statesChosen}}
  <ul>
    <li  *ngFor="let state of statesChosen">{{state.name}}</li>
  </ul>

  Area Name: <input formControlName="areaNameFormComponent"/>
  <br />
  Area Description: <input formControlName="areaDescriptionFormComponent"/>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="naturalAreaFormGroup.invalid">Add Natural Area</button>

</form>
```

It seems like the main issue here is that I am trying to use a FormControl for something that is not a form component since it's just an array that I am wanting checked to see if the array has any elements in it, but I don't know how to get the form group to be invalid until this array has elements in it and I need the formgroup to recheck the validation after elements are added to the array.

Comment: Put the custom validator on the formgroup itself, not a single form control.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this using `updateValueAndValidity`

```
areaNameFormComponent: AbstractControl;
areaDescriptionFormComponent: AbstractControl;
statesChosenFormComponent: AbstractControl;

constructor() {
    this.areaNameFormComponent = this.naturalAreaFormGroup.controls['areaNameFormComponent'];
    this.areaDescriptionFormComponent = this.naturalAreaFormGroup.controls['areaDescriptionFormComponent'];
    this.statesChosenFormComponent = this.naturalAreaFormGroup.controls['statesChosenFormComponent'];
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.naturalAreaFormGroup.get('areaNameFormComponent').valueChanges.subscribe(()=> revalidate());
    this.naturalAreaFormGroup .get('areaDescriptionFormComponent').valueChanges.subscribe(()=> revalidate());
    this.naturalAreaFormGroup .get('statesChosenFormComponent').valueChanges.subscribe(()=> revalidate());
}

revalidate(){
    this.areaNameFormComponent.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.areaDescriptionFormComponent.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.statesChosenFormComponent.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the form value:

```
stateChanged($event){
    this.naturalAreaFormGroup.patchValue({statesChosenFormComponent:statesChosen});
}
```

in the validator you can check the control.value only.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  In the code where a new state gets added after I add the state I call the FormControl from inside the FormGroup and run the "reset" method.
I now also know that you can pass validator functions to the FormGroup itself.
ie:

```
this.naturalAreaFormGroup.get('statesChosenFormComponent').reset();
```